# Executing large SQL file using sqlcmd not working blank log

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

There is no way for me to know where my script is failing and the log file is empty. The script only contains insert with where statement but somehow no error is shown in the log file. The sql file size is 301 MB.
The issue am having is that the script suppose to work or at least show error in the job_entry.log. No way to know where the script is even failing and why is not working. The log file is blank.

```
sqlcmd.exe -S 1.1.1.1 -d dbname -U user -P pass -b -i example.sql -o "job_entry.log"
```

Any reason why?

Comment: You've not explained any sort of problem at all. You've simply told us what you're doing. Are you asking us why you're doing it? If not, please [edit] your post and clearly explain the problem you're having.

Comment: @KenWhite The script is not working and no error is showing in the log to know where it is failing. Do I need to post part of the code in the sql script. But at least I expect it to throw error in the log fine regardless. In this case, nothing is showing.

Comment: "I am trying to run a .sql file using sqlcmd with 1.2 million line of codes" - WTAF! I think I see your actual problem....

Comment: But it is suggested that sqlcmd.exe could excute such file.  I have run at least 400, 000 lines of code in oracle developer without issue. seems ssms has too much limitation and now sqlcmd. I might need to split this script. Do you know any recommended limit on the  file size?